# JS Algorithm for linking nested array elements with their parent elements

Tags: javascript, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I'm looking for an algorithm to link nested elements in array to their parents. Probably recursively. Here's an array example https://jsfiddle.net/g2xh5r97/

I want to make every children of every element to have 'parentId' which will link it to ID of it's parent.
Every children of every element might have it's own children and it is unknown how deep this nesting could be.

For example:

```
arr[0].id === '1'; // (already has it's own ID)
arr[0].children[0].id === '1-1'; // (already has it's own ID
arr[0].children[0].parentId === '1';  // (parentId should be added to this element)
```

Here's how I try to do it

```
const linkNestedElements = (arr2, parentId) => {
  for (let item of arr2) {
  item.parentId = parentId;

  if (item.children && item.children.length) {
    item.children = linkNestedElements(item.children, item.id);
  }
  return arr2;
 }
}

const linkElements = (arr) => {
 for (let item of arr) {
  let currentId = item.id;
  if (item.children && item.children.length) {
    item.children = linkNestedElements(item.children, item.id)
  }
 }
 return arr;
}
```

It only modifies first nested elements and everything else is either ignored or get's deleted depending on variations of this

Comment: So you looked around... but what if you tried to *do* it? What is holding you back? Iterating the structure? Adding a property? Keeping track of the parent during the traversal? ... Tell us what the problem is you encountered and share your code.

Comment: @trincot I don't understand how to cycle through all children, it only modifies first in list and everything else is just ignored or get's deleted. Here's how I try to do it https://jsfiddle.net/oyu3tvgs/

Comment: Please edit your question and make sure the code is inside of it and not (only) behind a link.

Comment: @trincot added it to question body. hopefully it should be more obvious to read and understand now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is quite fine. But in the first function your loop is interrupted in its very first iteration. You need to move the `return` statement out of that loop:

```
const linkNestedElements = (arr2, parentId) => {
  for (let item of arr2) {
    item.parentId = parentId;

    if (item.children && item.children.length) {
      item.children = linkNestedElements(item.children, item.id);
    }
  }
  return arr2; // <--- moved here
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was looking at this for some time and couldn't notice this obvious problem. I guess one need's to take a break if something like this happening